# Codeigniter Sessions and Sharding

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, sharding

We are using Codeigniter in an app that is being sharded. This involves splitting the database across user ids. There are two kinds of tables in the sharded database - one is sharded by user id, so that the data is evenly split across multiple shards, and global, where the data is replicated across all shards.  We are also of course load balanced, so using the default php sessions doesn't work.

We like the CI sessions database for it's security, but we can't shard it, we are going to be hitting that table pretty heavily, and it's going to be replicated madly back and forth across all shards. This is not a good situation. Our load testing has indicated that the the ci_sessions table is already a pain point.

We have a couple of strategies for dealing with it. One, because we are using propel for an ORM, we can easily split ci_sessions, which uses CI's database access layer, off into a DB of it's own. We could even shard that one, if necessary.

I'm wondering whether there are other alternatives that people would suggest?

Comment: If you are splitting DB based on user id's wouldn't you just split the sessions amongst databases along the same user id lines?

Comment: Do you have an idea as to what the total size of the session data that you would need to hold at once will be?

Comment: Why not have multiple ci_session databases?  If you have multiple front ends with a load balancer that will ensure the same user's requests will always goes to the same server, you could have a dedicated database for each one and therefore would spread the load?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no userid available. We could change the session class, I suppose, but there is the possibility that the user would not be logged in yet.

Comment: You can't have multiple ci session tables if you can't guarantee that the user will come back to the same instance. That's the issue that the cookies and db solves.

Comment: Still not sure about total session data size. If the app works out, we could in theory millions of users, and hundreds of thousands logged in at any time. They don't have a lot of session data, we are not storing a lot of of variables. A few k each, I'd think. We are thinking about a single large Amazon RDS instance, with the data in a memory table - it's all ephemeral data.

Answer (score 0):

what about NOT using db session, or html5 session/local Storage? :)

or using cookies to set custom vars or ids or domain paths?

anyway it depends on how much session/cookie size you need for each user, sure db will guarantees more space and better security.

I love mongodb anyway :D https://github.com/sepehr/ci-mongodb-session

Comment: @user1598603 well i just reported things i will look for to resolve a situation like your if  i'll be in trouble in a similar situation, i'll think about all known possibilities ;) .. sorry for my bad english !